# Is it possible to remove groups plotted as point geom from the legend of a ggplot which has both line and point geom data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Hi I have a ggplot with point and line geoms in same graph. I have been asked to alter the legend so that point data is not represented as a point with line through. I have tried many ways but can not make it work.

Here is a frame with some dummy data and below it a few attempts

```
x_observed <- rep(c(100, 125,  140,  150, 180, 200,  300,  400), 50)
x_predict <- 0:399

y_observed <- rep(c(800, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 4500, 6000, 7000), 50)
y_predict1 <-  25*(x_predict - 45)
y_predict2 <-  24*(x_predict - 60)
y_predict3 <-  20*(x_predict - 110)

obs <- (rep(paste("obs"), 400))
pred1 <- (rep(paste("pred1"), 400))
pred2 <-  (rep(paste("pred2"), 400))
pred3 <-  (rep(paste("pred3"), 400))


x <- c(x_observed, x_predict1, x_predict2, x_predict3)
y <- c(y_observed, y_predict1, y_predict2, y_predict3)
group <- c(obs, pred1, pred2, pred3)

dat <- data.frame(x, y, group)
```

##### Graphs

###### this one is ok apart from legend of "obs" having a line

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x= x , y = y, colour = group))+ 
  geom_point(data = subset(dat, group == "obs")) +
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred1"))+
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred2"))+ 
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred3"))
```

###### Tried removing legend from point data only (just remove "obs" from legend would be ok)

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x= x , y = y, group = group))+ 
  geom_point(data = subset(dat, group == "obs"), colour = "blue", show.legend = F) +
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred1"), colour = "red", show.legend = T)+
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred2"), colour = "black")+ 
  geom_line(size=1.3,data = subset(dat, group == "pred3"), colour = "grey")
```

###### below legend as shapes is ok but then a line is plotted through "obs" which should only be point

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, group = group, colour=group, shape=group)) +
  geom_line ( show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point( ) + 
  labs( shape = "group", colour = "group")
```

###### again we have a line through the "obs" legend, even though i tried to remove it

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, group = group, colour=group)) +
  geom_line (data = subset(dat, group != "obs")) +
  geom_point(data = subset(dat, group == "obs" , show.legend = FALSE)) + 
  labs(  colour = "group")
```

If anyone can help it would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are trying to achieve. To adjust the legend you could make use of the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend`which allows you to set the `linetype` and `shape` of each legend entry manually. Be aware though that you have to set the values in the order the entries appear in your legend. Additionally I added a `scale_color_manual` to set the colors:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat,aes(x= x , y = y, colour = group))+ 
  geom_point(data = subset(dat, group == "obs")) +
  geom_line(size=1.3, data = subset(dat, !group == "obs")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(obs = "blue", pred1 = "red", pred2 = "black", pred3 = "grey")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(
    override.aes = list(
      linetype = c("blank", rep("solid", 3)),
      shape = c(16, rep(NA, 3)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was after.

Comment: Also for those wanting to run it there was an error in the x vector, should be x <- c(x_observed, x_predict, x_predict, x_predict). Thanks again Stefan most appreciated.